# Composing a plain text email in Google Groups

Tags: google-groups, text-formatting

Is it possible to compose a plain text email in Google Groups?

Clicking on the "New topic" button opens a rich text editor, and I see no option to switch to plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default , it is just plain text, until you change certain formatting options. 
(or paste in something with rich content, with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> rather than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

As an owner of a group, you could remove the rich formatting permission from selected members.